# Regex matching items following a header in HTML

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

What should be a fairly simple regex extraction is confounding me.  Couldn't find a similar question on SO, so happy to be pointed to one if it exists.  Given the following HTML:

`<h1 class="title">Title One</h1><p><a href="#">40.5</a><a href="#">31.3</a></p>`

`<h1 class="title alternate">Title Two</h1><p><a href="#">12.1</a><a href="#">82.0</a></p>`

(amongst a larger document - the extracts will most probably run across multiple lines)

How can I construct a regular expression that finds the text within the A tags, within the first P following an H1?  The regex will go in a loop, such that I can pass in the header, in order to retrieve the items that follow.

`<a[^>]*>([0-9.]+?)</a>` obviously matches all items in a tag (and should be fine as a tags cannot be nexted), but I can't tie them to an H1.

`.+Title One.+<a[^>]*>([0-9.]+?)</a></p>` fails.

I had tried to use look behind as so:

`(?<=Title One.+)<a[^>]*>([0-9.]+?)</a></p>` and some variations but it is only allowed for fixed width matches (which won't be the case here).

For context, this will be using Python's regex engine.  I know regex isn't necessarily the best solution for this, so alternative suggestions using DOM or something else also gratefully received :)

---

**Update**

To clarify from the above, I'd like to get back the following:

`{"Title One": ["40.5", "31.3"], "Title Two": ["12.1", "82.0"]}`

(not that I need help composing the dictionary, but it does demonstrate how I need the values to be related to the title).

So far BeautifulSoup looks like the best shot.  LXML will also probably work as the source HTML isn't really tag-soup - it's pretty well-structured, at least in the places I'm interested in.

---

Comment: Will this run in serverside code or in javascript within the document?

Comment: This is for a standalone python script, not actually web-based.  HTML is just the source data.

Comment: Do you have control over the created HTML, can you trust it to follow any common format?

Comment: No direct control, but I can trust it to match the above format pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> data = """
... <h1 class="title">Title One</h1><p><a href="#">40.5</a><a href="#">31.3</a></p>
... <h1 class="title alternate">Title Two</h1><p><a href="#">12.1</a><a href="#">82.0</a></p>
... """
>>>
>>> d = etree.HTML(data)
>>> d.xpath('//h1/following-sibling::p[1]/a/text()')
['40.5', '31.3', '12.1', '82.0']
```

This solution uses `lxml.etree` and an `xpath` expression.

---

**Update**

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> data = """
... <h1 class="title">Title One</h1><p><a href="#">40.5</a><a href="#">31.3</a></p>
... <h1 class="title alternate">Title Two</h1><p><a href="#">12.1</a><a href="#">82.0</a></p>
... """
>>>
>>> d = etree.HTML(data)
>>> #d.xpath('//h1[following-sibling::*[1][local-name()="p"]]') 
...
>>> results = {}
>>> for h in d.xpath('//h1[following-sibling::*[1][local-name()="p"]]'):
...   r = results.setdefault(str(h.text),[])
...   r += [ str(x) for x in h.xpath('./following-sibling::*[1][local-name()="p"]/a/text()') ]
...
>>> pprint(results)
{'Title One': ['40.5', '31.3'], 'Title Two': ['12.1', '82.0']}
```

Now using predicates to look ahead, this should iterate through `<h1>` tags which are immediately followed by `<p>` tags. ( Casting `tag.text` to strings explicitly as I have a recollection that they aren't normal strings, you'd have trouble pickling them, etc.)

Comment: It is, although there will be other H1 elements on the page and I'll need to know which values go with which title.  Hadn't considered XPATH, will investigate, thanks.

Comment: If you post what you're parsing and what you need out of it. I'm sure someone can point you in the right direction with xpath.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to come back to this, but this is awesome and exactly what I needed :)  Took me about an hour to grok though - xpath not my strong suit!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, regex is absolutely the wrong tool for HTML matching.

Your question, however, sounds exactly like the problem for [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) - a HTML parser that can deal with less-than-perfect HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The other obvious answer to solve this problem is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) -- I like that it handles the kind of crappy html that you often run into out in the wild as sensibly and gracefully as you can hope.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse html. That can't be done, by definition. Use a html parser instead. I suggest `lxml.html`.

`lxml.html` deals with badly formed html better than BeautifulSoup, is actively maintained (BeautifulSoup isn't) and is a lot faster since it uses `libxml2` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using just normal string manipulation

```
html='''
<h1 class="title">Title One</h1><p><a href="#">40.5</a>
<a href="#">31.3</a></p>
<h1 class="title alternate">Title Two</h1><p><a href="#">12.1</a><a href="#">82.0</a></p>
'''

for i in html.split("</a>"):
    if "<a href" in i:
        print i.split("<a href")[-1].split(">")[-1]
```

output

```
$ python test.py
40.5
31.3
12.1
82.0
```

I don't actually understand what you want to get, but if your requirement is SIMPLE, yes, a regex or a few string mangling can do it. Not necessary need a parser for that.

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, but doesn't match the values to the titles.  I'll clarify the question.